# Ramp up time for 1000 users

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Please tell me for 1000 users ,how much ramp up time shall I give,so that in Jmeter report also 1000 users should come.I have tried every combination almost but failed.And I want to test it in a given loop count,not in forever mode.
For example i have ran test for 1000 users with 1000 sec ramp up time and loop count to be 1,but the in jmeter report,only 12 users are shown to be active/virtual users.So please tell me the correct combination.
And if I talk about graph listener,why it is start from end direction,that is from the opposite direction where it should end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misunderstanding described in [Max Users is Lower than Expected](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/147922-max-users-is-lower-than-expected) article.

In [official documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html) it's recommended to start with

> Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.

If you need to limit test execution time you can use [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller). If your goal is to simulate 1000 requests per second - you should be using [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer).

[Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) allows configuring ramp-up, ramp-down and time to hold the load period in easy visual way.

[image: Ultimate Thread Group]

Choose any above option or combination according to you load test scenario or elaborate the question so we could suggest the best one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified 1000 users, but only 12 are shown to run in the test report, its possible that your test duration is set too low.

Try changing the thread group settings to those in the screenshot, does that help?

[image: Jmeter Thread Group settings]

Comment: Actually,by setting or configured the thread group as you did,my system hangs  because of system limitation.Can you please tell me why you set loop count to 5 and  duration to be 10000 sec for 1000 users.If i try with 100 or 500 users,then what should be loop count or duration to be set.

Comment: If I use runtime controller or constant throuput timer,then what should be the values to be input in it.If I test for 100 or 500 users,the what should be runtime seconds in runtime controller and target throuput in constant throughput timer.I mean what sort of calculation is required to set those values.

Comment: My numbers were just an example to see if you could get more users (threads) than 12 over a period of time. If 1000 users is crashing the system, then scale down and try first with 10, then 20 etc.

Comment: There is no formula to calculate the numbers you are asking for, it all depends on the system you are testing. As mentioned above by Dmitri, the Ultimate Thread group will be more useful to you, since it has a nice chart showing the number of users that will be activate for the lifecycle of the test